# pyqt - Drag&Drop rows in table fails to drag images and widgets in cells

Tags: python, pyqt

i used a class from stackoverflow that applies the drag and drop feature to table rows but it doesn't save images from being removed from cells when dragging and dropping any row i want some help figuring out how to fix the code to do this jop right !
the code of the whole project with database:
database used: https://gofile.io/d/c0srQ0

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
QVBoxLayout, QStyledItemDelegate, QCheckBox, QTableWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView, QTableWidget)

import sqlite3
import random
import ast
#import qdarkstyle

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.cashed = []
        self.setWindowTitle('Arabic Math Project')
        self.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        # create table:
        #Options()
        #self.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet())
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.searchBar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.searchBar.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.searchBar.setPlaceholderText("search")
        self.searchBar.textChanged.connect(self.startSearchThreading) #editingFinished()
        #self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

        self.table = TableWidgetDragRows()
     
        conn = sqlite3.connect("math.db")
        conn.text_factory = bytes
        self.cur = conn.cursor()


        data = self.cur.execute("select * from problems;").fetchall();conn.close()
        self.dims = (lambda x: (len(x), len(x[0])))(data) #(rows number, col number)

        [self.table.insertRow(i) for i in [i for i in range(self.dims[0])]]
        [self.table.insertColumn(i) for i in [i for i in range(self.dims[1]+1)]]

        #changing h-header names .
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Unique", "Image", "Test", "Year", "Lesson", "Page","Comment", "Options", "Options-advanced"])

        for c in range(self.dims[1]):
            for r in range(self.dims[0]):
                if c!=1:self.table.setItem(r, c, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[r][c].decode("utf-8"))) 
                else:self.table.setCellWidget(r, c, self.getImage(data[r][c]))

        for r in range(self.dims[0]):self.table.setCellWidget(r, self.dims[1], Options(ops=[data[r][self.dims[1]-1].decode("utf-8")], row=data[r]))



        #table h & v  auto - resizing . 
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Interactive)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(7, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Interactive)
        headerv = self.table.verticalHeader()
        headerv.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        #hide the options column cuz it doesn't concern user to see it.
        self.table.setColumnHidden(7, True)

        #layout setting up.
        layout.addWidget(self.searchBar)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def getImage(self, image):
        imageLabel = ScaledPixmapLabel()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(image, "jpg")
        imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        return imageLabel

    def startSearchThreading(self):
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        self.update = updateTable(data= self.searchBar.text())
        self.update.new_signal.connect(self.Search)
        self.update.start()

    def create(self):
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        return self.formGroupBox

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int, bytes, bool, bytes)
    def Search(self, r, c, d, newRowOrder, ops):
        if newRowOrder:self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount()) # create new row.        
        if c!=1:self.table.setItem(r, c, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(d.decode("utf-8"))) 
        else:self.table.setCellWidget(r, c, self.getImage(d))
        self.cashed.append(d)
        if c ==self.dims[1]-1:
            self.table.setCellWidget(r, self.dims[1], Options(ops=[ops.decode("utf-8")], row=self.cashed))
            self.cashed = []


class updateTable(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, data=True):
        super(QtCore.QThread, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, bytes, bool, bytes)

    def run(self):
        currRow = 0
        conn = sqlite3.connect("math.db")
        conn.text_factory = bytes
        self.cur = conn.cursor()
        searched = self.cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM problems WHERE text LIKE ('%' || ? || '%') ", (self.data,)).fetchall()
        dims = (lambda x: (len(x), len(x[0])))(searched) if searched!=[] else (0, 0)
        for r in range(dims[0]):
            for c in range(dims[1]):
                self.new_signal.emit(r, c, searched[r][c], True if c==0 else False, searched[r][dims[1]-1])



class ScaledPixmapLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScaledContents(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.pixmap():
            pm = self.pixmap()
            originalRatio = pm.width() / pm.height()
            currentRatio = self.width() / self.height()
            if originalRatio != currentRatio:
                qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
                pm = self.pixmap().scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
                rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, pm.width(), pm.height())
                rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
                qp.drawPixmap(rect, pm)
                return
        super().paintEvent(event)

class Options(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,row=[], ops=[]):
        super(Options, self).__init__(parent)
        self.i = random.randint(1, 100)
        self.row = [j.decode("utf-8") if i!=1 else "image" for i,j in enumerate(row)]
        self.formLayout = QFormLayout()
        self.setStyleSheet(open("styles.css").read())
        ops = ast.literal_eval(ops[0]) if ops!=[] else {}
        for i,j in ops.items():
            widget = {"lineedit": QLineEdit(), "combobox": QComboBox(), "spinbox": QSpinBox(), "checkbox": QCheckBox()}

            title  = j.get("title", "")
            combos = j.get("combos", [])

            if i == "lineedit":widget[i].setText(j.get("default", ""))
            elif i == "combobox":widget[i].addItems(combos)
            elif i == "checkbox":
                widget[i].setCheckState((lambda x: {1:2, 2:2, 0:0}[x])(j.get("default", 0)))
                widget[i].setText(j.get("text", ""))
            elif i == "spinbox":
                widget[i].setMaximum(j.get("max", 100))
                widget[i].setMinimum(j.get("min", 0))

            self.formLayout.addRow(QLabel(title), widget[i])

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Submit")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.do)
        self.formLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.formLayout.setFormAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setLayout(self.formLayout)

    def do(self):
        #[STOPED HERE]
        heads, tails = [], []
        for i in range(self.formLayout.count()):
            w = self.formLayout.itemAt(i).widget()
            if i%2==0:heads.append(w.text())
            elif isinstance(w, QLineEdit):tails.append(w.text())
            elif isinstance(w, QComboBox):tails.append(w.currentText())
            elif isinstance(w, QSpinBox):tails.append(w.value())
            elif isinstance(w, QCheckBox):tails.append(w.checkState())

        values = {i:j for i,j in zip(heads, tails)}
        print(self.row[:-1]+[values])

class TableWidgetDragRows(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)

        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        #self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

    def dropEvent(self, event: QDropEvent):
        if not event.isAccepted() and event.source() == self:
            drop_row = self.drop_on(event)

            rows = sorted(set(item.row() for item in self.selectedItems()))
            print(rows)
            rows_to_move = [[QTableWidgetItem(self.item(row_index, column_index)) for column_index in range(self.columnCount())]
                            for row_index in rows]
            for row_index in reversed(rows):
                self.removeRow(row_index)
                if row_index < drop_row:
                    drop_row -= 1

            for row_index, data in enumerate(rows_to_move):
                row_index += drop_row
                self.insertRow(row_index)
                for column_index, column_data in enumerate(data):
                    self.setItem(row_index, column_index, column_data)
            event.accept()
            for row_index in range(len(rows_to_move)):
                self.item(drop_row + row_index, 0).setSelected(True)
                self.item(drop_row + row_index, 1).setSelected(True)
        super().dropEvent(event)

    def drop_on(self, event):
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if not index.isValid():
            return self.rowCount()

        return index.row() + 1 if self.is_below(event.pos(), index) else index.row()

    def is_below(self, pos, index):
        rect = self.visualRect(index)
        margin = 2
        if pos.y() - rect.top() < margin:
            return False
        elif rect.bottom() - pos.y() < margin:
            return True
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        return rect.contains(pos, True) and not (int(self.model().flags(index)) & Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled) and pos.y() >= rect.center().y()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.resize(600,600)
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: How are you setting the images? If you're using a `QLabel` with `setCellWidget`, you should use it again when you create the new item: the cell widget is completely indepentent from the model, and QTableWidgetItem doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: this is a bit confusing for me, idk how creating new items related to drag&drop!,  and where to use setCellWidget() in the prev class?

Comment: Please, answer the question: how are you setting the images?

Comment: i put the image inside a label then used setCellWidget() as u said !

Comment: @musicamante will posting the whole code make it better to see it clearer !

Comment: Always provide minimal reproducible examples, as context is always important: remember that StackOverflow is not only a place for "you" to get answers, but for everybody to find them if they have been asked already. If somebody has an issue similar to yours and finds your question, that somebody won't know about the "other" question.

Comment: @musicamante okay i will keep that in mind, i did add the whole code with the database please check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting images using QLabels set as cell widgets. Setting cell widgets is only a feature used by the table UI: it is completely unrelated to the underlying model and the QTableWidgetItems know nothing about them also. So, it's completely up to you to check if a cell has a widget set and move that widget accordingly.

Semi pseudo-code:

```
    def dropEvent(self, event: QDropEvent):
        if not event.isAccepted() and event.source() == self:
            drop_row = self.drop_on(event)

            rows = sorted(set(item.row() for item in self.selectedItems()))
            print(rows)
            rows_to_move = []
            images = []
            for row_index in rows:
                items = []
                for column_index in range(self.columnCount()):
                    items.append(QTableWidgetItem(
                        self.item(row_index, column_index)))
                    widget = self.cellWidget(row_index, column_index)
                    if isinstance(widget, ScaledPixmapLabel):
                        images.append((row_index, column_index, widget.pixmap()))
                rows_to_move.append(items)
            # ...
            for row, column, pixmap in widgets:
                self.setCellWidget(row + drop_row, column,
                    ScaledPixmapLabel(pixmap))
```

As you can see I recreated the label instance each time, that's because when you set a cell widget, the table takes its ownership. While you could reparent the widget, the result might be undefined, so it's better to create a brand new instance based on the pixmap.

<sub>Tip: avoid using inline `if/else` or `for` loops: there's absolutely no benefit in doing it, and the only result is that it makes your code much less readable</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, because I don't know what you need to use that data with or how you're dealing with it. From what I see from your code, I would have not used QTableWidget, but a QTableView with a QSqlTableModel directly connected to the database. Then I'd have used a QStyledItemDelegate for the image column as well. In this way, the whole structure would have been much more straightforward. And I wouldn't have used a QThread for data filtering, QSortFilterProxyModel exists exactly for that reason. I strongly suggest you to study the above classes and do some research.

Comment: Wow that's alot to process i would delete it all and start over followin all of ur steps to develop my app, i ended doin this cuz i'm only searching without having some reference to tell me wut is best but you enlightened me now, i wish this library had a decent documentation for python, anyway thank you very much for helping me

Comment: I know it might seem a big step, but you've not gone "too far" yet, and there are two very good aspects about reimplementing like that: 1. you're going to learn how to use those classes (and learn when to choose between a QTableWidget and a QTableView), 2. using a more appropriate interface for your data means that whenever you need to go back to it for debugging or further implementation, it would have more sense and will be much easier to recall what the code is doing (since it's using a more correct way to deal with your data).

Comment: About the documentation, I suggest you to follow the official one; despite being written for C++ developers, 99% of functions work in the same way with PyQt. It will take you some time (but not that much) to understand and "translate" some of the terminology or the examples, but it's worth it, and it's far more complete and readable than the PyQt docs, which you can still examine for special cases in which PyQt has slightly different behavior/arguments (some functions have overloads that are available on python only). Also consider using `help(className.functionName)` in the python shell.